# how to find the topper of a university using mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

Suppose every institute sends their result set to the university in a file and from those files we need to find the topper of the university. Please provide the mapper, reducer and driver code for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [code](https://github.com/dgadiraju/code/tree/master/hadoop/nyse/src/main/java/nyse/topthreestocksbyvolume) in github as reference. You can download the code and make the necessary changes to it.

It computes top three stocks per day by volume from the data which have stock name and volume along with other fields. Also you can create hive table and write sql query very easily for it.